# Facebook yoga/react-native flexbox css-layout position: "fixed" support

Tags: css, layout, react-native, fullscreen

For support of position: "fixed" in css-layout(react-native),

**Use case:** I have (many) videoView deeply nested in view hierarchy - think list of videos,
any one of which I want to make fullscreen.

**Current approach (hack):**
make videoview as big as screen(fixed values for height width in css style),
track videoview's parent layout position and give negative margins to videview to show it properly.

**Desired approach:** Was wondering if there is a simple way to do this
(like `position: fixed`)

Any suggestions or help is welcome

Comment: I really don't get this site.  Why is this being upvoted when it is clearly off topic for the site? And much better questions than this get down-voted.  What is so good about this question that it has been upvoted 4 times?

Comment: @Pete Probably just because it is React related... and flexbox which isn't even relevant to the question.

Comment: @Ricky exactly - even the title makes no sense.  I may try that for my next question, add react to it and see if it gets upvoted for no reason!

Comment: @Pete haha, but then I'd have to search for react to actually see CSS related questions `:(` ..  Seriously, I hope this gets closed soon.

Comment: by css-layout i mean https://github.com/facebook/css-layout

Comment: this is known by facebook-yoga - https://github.com/facebook/yoga

Comment: Hey @jayshah did you manage to find a solution to this? I